Sorted dict with str+int keys in python
I was trying to sort a dict, where i had values such as:
'e0', 'e3', 'e9', ...
but sadly python sorts it by "first letters", and when i have an 'e12' value it puts it before 'e3'
can someone pls help me write a function which will sort it well
example dict for sorting:
{'e0': 50, 'e12': 89, 'e3': 110, 'e90': 18, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40}
expected result:
{'e0': 50, 'e3': 110, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40, 'e12': 89, 'e90': 18}
I've tried to do it sorted(); of course, it didn't work, but I also tried
sorted(thedict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

but it doesn't work correctly too (described in the beginning)


I'd save the keys as tuple ('e', 12), before creating the dict().

If that's not an option, then you have to break it apart and get the number and sort it based on that:


def _sort_dict(d):
    def _by_num(key):
        return int(key[1:])

    return dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: _by_num(x[0])))

print(_sort_dict({'e0': 50, 'e12': 89, 'e3': 110, 'e90': 18, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40}))


Prints

{'e0': 50, 'e3': 110, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40, 'e12': 89, 'e90': 18}

Note

If the alpha part was longer, we can get the ending digits:


import re

def _sort_dict(d):
    def _by_num(key):
        num = re.search(r'\d*$', key)[0]
        return int(num) if num else -1

    return dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: _by_num(x[0])))


print(_sort_dict({'eeee0': 50, 'eeee12': 89, 'eeee3': 110, 'ee90': 18, 'eaaa8': 82, 'ebbb11': 40, 'eeee': 50}))


Prints

{'eeee': 50, 'eeee0': 50, 'eeee3': 110, 'eaaa8': 82, 'ebbb11': 40,
'eeee12': 89, 'ee90': 18}


Note:
If you may have had, only alphas, or only numeric or both, you can use this pattern, r'(^[^0-9]*)(\d*)$', generate a tuple of (alpha, numeric) and then sort it:
Code
import re


def _sort_dict(d):
    def _by_num(key):
        p = r'(^[^0-9]*)(\d*)$'
        alpha, num = re.findall(p, key)[0]
        return (alpha, int(num if num else -1))

    return dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: _by_num(x[0])))


print(_sort_dict({'eeee0': 50, 'eeee12': 89, 'eeee3': 110,
      'ee90': 18, 'eaaa8': 82, 'ebbb11': 40, 'eeee': 50, '0': 50}))


Prints

{'0': 50, 'eaaa8': 82, 'ebbb11': 40, 'ee90': 18, 'eeee': 50, 'eeee0':
50, 'eeee3': 110, 'eeee12': 89}


You are in the right direction, you just need to slice the number part
dict(sorted(thedict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:])))

or with regex if you might have more than 1 letter
dict(sorted(thedict.items(), key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+$', x[0]).group())))

and then convert it back to a dict
Output
{'e0': 50, 'e3': 110, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40, 'e12': 89, 'e90': 18}


Preface:
Dictionaries are only insertion sorted (and even that only from Python 3.6+) - you can't really "sort" them per se, you'd have to create a new dictionary from scratch inserting keys in a given order, but that will break as soon as you add a new key that should not be at the end.
That being said, in order to sort the keys you have by number they contain, you need to convert them to int, as strings use lexical sorting, rather natural sort.
d = {'e0': 50, 'e12': 89, 'e3': 110, 'e90': 18, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40}

print(sorted(d, key = lambda x: int(x[1:])))

Sort key function removes first element from the key (assumed to be "e") and then converts key to integer, allowing sorting by value. This returns correctly sorted list of keys:
['e0', 'e3', 'e8', 'e11', 'e12', 'e90']

If you want to recreate the dictionary, you can use d.items() and extract keys from the tuples:
print(dict(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: int(x[0][1:]))))

Output:
{'e0': 50, 'e3': 110, 'e8': 82, 'e11': 40, 'e12': 89, 'e90': 18}

But, as I've already mentioned, this sorted property will be very fragile and possibly break on any inserts to dictionary.
PS.
Should you want to handle more cases than just exx keys, you can natural order sort. There is a Python library for that called natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

d = {'e0': 50, 'ee12': 89, 'e3': 110, 'ee90': 18, 'eb8': 82, 'e11': 40}

print(dict(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: natsort_key(x[0]))))

Output:
{'e0': 50, 'e3': 110, 'e11': 40, 'eb8': 82, 'ee12': 89, 'ee90': 18}

